# Custom login page in Spring Security 5 using oauth2 returns null

Tags: spring, security, authentication, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am developing custom login page in `Spring Security 5` using `oauth2`. So I have customized settings:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login().loginPage("/login/oauth2").permitAll();
    }
```

and creating `controller` with `@RequestMapping("/login/oauth2")`:

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login/oauth2")
    public String login(Model model, OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) {
        return "login";
    }
```

The `login.html` page is a regular form which redirect to `login` method from controller:

```
 <h1>Logowanie</h1>
<a>ZALOGUJ</a>
<a class="btn" href="/login/oauth2/code/google">Login</a>
```

With this configuration `OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication` is null and therefore authentication can't be applied. With default `Spring Security 5` configuration everything works fine. The example on which I based is described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-advanced-login-page; section `31.1 OAuth 2.0 Login Page`.

Comment: What do you do in your controller method? This method should only render your custom loging page (your HTML). And why do you send the form to your login page instead of your authorization endpoint?

Comment: I don't discuss the official example, I discuss your controller method. The documentation says: *You need to provide a @Controller with a @RequestMapping("/login/oauth2") that is capable of rendering the custom login page.*

Comment: Ok, maybe you are right. So are you able to provide some kind of 'logic' how it should be done? Beacuse rendering I think is not a big deal but then how app will know that "now" it should be redirected to let's say "Google login page"?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? You have to support a link to the authentication point: *`<a href="/oauth2/authorization/google">Google</a>`* Your login page only contains a link to itself.

Comment: Your edited login page has a link to `/login/oauth2/code/google`, but the documenation says `/oauth2/authorization/google`.

Answer (score 1):

In my app to work I had to create my custom WebMvc configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
}
```

Then in WebSecurityConfig:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }
```

I think in this case You don't need custom controller.

I wrote a blog post about silent token refresh in implicit flow, but there You will find full working app with custom login page:

https://regulargeek.blogspot.com/2018/05/angular-5-springboot-2-oauth2-and.html